# How to retrieve pixel data from direct2D

Tags: windows-7, direct2d

How can I do this?
If I apply some d2d effect, then how can I retrieve pixel data from it?
just point out its rgba value..
I already survey the all d2d api, but can't find some relative api.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct2D does not provide the interfaces to manipulate pixels, but you can use [WIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(Direct2D also use WIC to manipulate bitmaps) instead.

1. Call [ID2D1Factory::CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the
   render target data, this function will return the IWICBitmap interface.
2. Use [Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ee690187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [CopyPixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee690179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods from this interface to get the pixel data.